# External interface connection SWF(xcelsius) and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, interface, connection, flash

I'm trying to pass a string to a Swf file embedded on Html through External interface connection.

It works when a do it with a button:

`<button onclick="grupos.setDataSource('user','Billy');">Change Data</button>`

But when i try with a script:

```
<script>grupos.setDataSource('user','Billy');</script>
```

i get the error **"Object has no method 'setDataSource'"**

I dont want to force people to press a button to pass the user to the swf. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Object has no method 'setDataSource'"** occurs when the .swf is not fully loaded.

This function in javascript will set the Data Source until its fully loaded thruogh setInterval:

```
function setAttribute(){
          var attributes = {
           id: "grupos",
            name: "grupos"
          };
          swfobject.embedSWF("grupos.swf", "grupos", "1025", "678", "9.0.0", attributes);
           var i = 1;
              var sInt = setInterval(function() {
                if(i >= 10) {
                  clearInterval(sInt);
                }else{
                  i++;
               }
               document.getElementById("grupos").innerHTML = "<object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"SWFObjects/test_" + i + ".swf\" width=\"300\" height=\"120\">";
              grupos.setDataSource('user','Billy');
           }, 500);
        }
```